# How to build an chrome extension like Google Hangouts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The [Google Hangouts extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd) has a panel that shows up outside of the Chrome UI.

It is sort of like a notification but not. I don't see anything in the Extension Developer Docs that describes an API to make this work. Is this a Google-specific hack they're doing? Is there something in the experimental APIs that I'm missing?

Comment: Related: [How does extension chat for google create the panel window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614493/how-does-extension-chat-for-google-create-the-panel-window "How does extension chat for google create the panel window?")

Answer (score 22):

It is an options of [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create). Make sure you set `type` to `panel`.

```
chrome.windows.create({ url: 'https://mobile.twitter.com/', type: 'panel' });
```

`panel` may not be supported on all platforms and you may have to specifically enable panels in Chrome Flags `chrome://flags/#enable-panels`.

Comment: I didn't enable `panel`, but `hangouts` manage to create one anyway.

Comment: Some of the Google extensions do panels automatically on some platforms.

Comment: @satoru what do you mean with "I didn't enable panel"?

Comment: There is an experimental flag in chrome you can flip that enables panels for non-whitelisted extension.

Comment: I see, it's `enable-panels` (chrome://flags/#enable-panels). So that means you cannot really create panels without the user enabling this flag, right?

Comment: Correct. (Last i checked)

Comment: it has been 4 years. is there a way now?

Comment: I don't believe much has changed.

Comment: @VikasBansal Nope, and an extension is still less powerful than an app.