# How can I make a Chrome extension that floats on the desktop?

Tags: .net, objective-c, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

I'm interested in making an in-house chrome extension for data management. I'm interested in mimicking the Google Hangouts extension, though. Specifically, how it resides in the system tray and can be popped out.

I've looked around and haven't found much documentation about this type of extension; would anyone know where to look for this?

I'm hoping that hangouts doesn't have special privaledges that only Google first-party extensions can have, or something.

Thanks alot

Comment: Related: [How does extension chat for google create the panel window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614493/how-does-extension-chat-for-google-create-the-panel-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a Chrome App.

Here is an excerpt from [Chrome Development Site](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps):

> Chrome Apps deliver an experience as capable as a native app, but as
>   safe as a web page. Just like web apps, Chrome Apps are written in
>   HTML5, JavaScript, and CSS. But Chrome Apps look and behave like
>   native apps, and they have native-like capabilities that are much more
>   powerful than those available to web apps.

Comment: Thank you for answering this old question!