# Chrome extension closes when I click on the page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As stated in the title, the Chrome extension I've been developing closes whenever I click on the page, and I noticed that this happens with all the other extensions that I have.

I really have 2 doubts:

1. Whether it is actually possible to leave the extension open
   regardless of whether the user clicks the screen or not;
2. If it is possible to force the extension to open via Content_Script;

Comment: You can't do that

Comment: @Doc-Han Ty for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume by "extension closes" you mean that a *popup* in your extension closes.

This is indeed normal behavior [that you cannot override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25806017/934239) if you click away.

It's also [not possible to open a popup from your code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10479679/934239) in Chrome.

So if you need some UI that co-exists with a page you interact with, you'd need to inject it into the page itself. Probably using Shadow DOM so that the page's styling doesn't interfere with yours.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It clarified my doubts. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @xan Please check my question if you know the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63500467/pause-a-download-with-chrome-doesnt-work-as-expected)