# pause a download with chrome doesnt work as expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to puase a download but it doesnt work, the file is downloaded. here my code:

In my background script:

```
chrome.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function (e) {
    chrome.downloads.pause(e.id);
});
```

Here [chrome.downloads.pause](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-pause) the API documentation

Comment: If anyone interested in having a solution to this problem, support this ticket on Chrominium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1458828#c3