# How do I customize the title bar of a popup in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do i style the title bar of a popup in a chrome extension? I notice this being done by [Chat for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chat-for-google/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?hl=en). (Note: the screenshot for that one is outdated)

I got as far as opening a popup without the address bar. But can't get on from there

The title bar itself is not part of the HTML upon inspection.

Example here:

[image: Header from the popup for Hangouts]

Comment: Duplicate: [How to build an extension like Chat for Google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487446/how-to-build-an-extension-like-chat-for-google) -- use `type: panel` in [`chrome.windows.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#method-create)

Comment: Or by "*opening a popup without the address bar*" do you mean you are *already* using `type: panel` and need further assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this isn't a regular chrome extension I was looking at. It's a [chrome packaged app](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html). And it's possible to remove the title bars with chrome apps.

Answer (score 0):

The window in the screenshot you show does have the title bar in the HTML/CSS.

Comment: My bad. I meant how to *style* it. I posted a screenshot.

Comment: If you inspect the the popup however, you'd find out that the title bar is outside the <html>.

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching this topic much and I surely know that Hangouts is a extension, not a packaged app.

I believe the extension windows are modified desktop notifications. I go to create an extension using these modified desktop notifications and i will report the result here.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.