# How to make Chrome Extension title bar like Google Hangouts?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-hangouts

This isn't working:

[How to build an chrome extension like Google Hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487446/how-to-build-an-chrome-extension-like-google-hangouts)

My question is similar to this:

[How do I customize the title bar of a popup in a chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533312/how-do-i-customize-the-title-bar-of-a-popup-in-a-chrome-extension)

I used `chrome.windows.create({...type:panel});` but its appearance is like this:

[image]

Is it possible to customize 'Normal title bar' area ?

codes here.

```
var createWindow = function (tab) {
  if (appWindow) {
    chrome.windows.remove(appWindow.id);
  }
  chrome.windows.create({
    tabId: tab.id,
    url: 'http://localhost:8080', 
    left: Math.round(screen.width - 300),
    top: Math.round(screen.height - 500),
    width: 300,
    height: 500,
    type: 'panel'
  }, function(win) {
    appWindow = win;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(appWindow.tabs[0].id, { file: './js/app_inject.js'}, function(){
         // console.log('inject executed'); 
        });
  });
};
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(createWindow);
```

"//localhost:8080" is my local server page.

Comment: Can you give the source code you are working with so that we can help you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your (apparently simple) question implies a couple more questions, so I'll try to split that up and address each one separately:

---

***1.*** Why does my "panel" look different than Hangouts ?

Hangouts opens as a panel (so it is styled as such).
Your "panel" opens as a popup (so it is styled as such).

---

***2.*** Why does my "panel" open as a popup ?

In order for an extension to be able to open panel-windows, the user must have this (experimental) feature enabled (and of course the underlying OS must support it). If panels are not enabled, all windows of type 'panel' or 'detached_panel' open as type 'popup' (**[documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html#property-createData-type)**).

---

***3.*** How can a user enable panels ?

Navigate to `chrome://flags/#enable-panels` and click `Enable`.

---

***4.*** How is it possible for Hangouts to open panel-windows when the flag is disabled ?

Short answer: It is white-listed in the source code.
Longer answer: Take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614493/how-does-extension-chat-for-google-create-the-panel-window#answer-11614605)**.

---

***5.*** Can I style the title-bar of a popup ?

Not really. The title-bar displays (among other things) the title of the page, so you can customize that part :)

---

***6.*** Do I have an alternative ?

If you absolutely need to be able to style your window, you could use a **[Packaged App](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html)**. Apps can open **[frameless windows](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html#property-options-frame)**, so you can create (and style) a title-bar using HTML/CSS.

Comment: Note that 'panel' now is deprecated and is available only to existing whitelisted extensions on Chrome OS. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-CreateType

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to start a hangout and copy a link to that hangout with 1 click, check out this extension (this is apparently still not an easy thing to do with Google+):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/one-click-google-hangout/aokjakdncnbbfhhammcdkbblmcglpobn