# How do I launch a frameless window from a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, window

I'm looking to achieve something similar to [Bitly's Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bitly-unleash-the-power-o/iabeihobmhlgpkcgjiloemdbofjbdcic/related?hl=en). It's not exactly frameless but the style of the title bar is minimal. Also, unlike other types of windows, in Mac OS you can maximize the main browser window and spawn Bitly's window on top.

Neither window.open nor [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create) offer any options to remove the frame of a launched window. And when these windows are spawned from a fullscreen browser window (maximized) they are also maximized and cannot be used on top of the current browser window.

[Chrome.app.window.create](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create) does expose the option to remove the frame but this only works for Chrome Apps and not extensions.

[image: Bitly Chrome Extension]

Neither of these potential duplicate questions sufficiently answer my question:

- [How do I customize the title bar of a popup in a chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533312/how-do-i-customize-the-title-bar-of-a-popup-in-a-chrome-extension)
- [How to build an chrome extension like Google Hangouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487446/how-to-build-an-chrome-extension-like-google-hangouts) (panels are deprecated)

Comment: It's a built-in browser window displayed by chrome.identity API.

Comment: Thanks. This essentially answers my question.