# Is it possible to create a frameless screen sharable window object from a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to share the content of a chrome tab without its frame (url, title, tabs, etc).
I know it's possible to create a window that has no address bar with a Chrome extension, but it still has a title.
Is it possible to create a window that has no frame at all with a Chrome extension?

Comment: If the solution from @MimiEAM doesn't suit your needs, you might also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675219/how-do-i-launch-a-frameless-window-from-a-google-chrome-extension as it mentions a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you don't mind having that tab opened in a new window.
Just set the window type to **popup**.  See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-create for more details

```
chrome.windows.create({
  url: 'http://www.google.com',
  type: 'popup'
})
```

It will look like so
[image]