# How to show an tray icon with a Google Packaged App or extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to create a tray icon for my Chrome Packaged App (an icon in the system status bar). Like the Google Hangout extension do, I want the app to make something (open a menu) when the user click the icon.

After some search, I've found this : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QhhfR33Y28Yqnnoa_Sl3fnZK_mKtwt4dZe6kNyJ_MjU/edit
It seems to be an old project from the chromium team of an experimental API that is doing what I'm searching. But it's not working for me. (Is it really for Packaged App ?)

If it's can't be done for an Packaged App, it's not really a problem for me, I can switch to a Chrome Extension. But I can't find do for extension either.

I think that if the Hangout extension can do this, I can do this too but I don't find anything on it.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I am not sure about Apps, but I doubt Extensions can have tray-icons. Just because the Hangout can do this, it doesn't mean you can too. There are several things (i.e. priviledges for Hangout and other Google stuff) hard-coded into the Chrome code, so our mortal Extensions cannot do everything that Hangout can do.

Comment: Ok thank, it seems that's I've found an other response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306548/how-to-use-system-indicator-in-the-manisfet-of-a-chrome-packaged-app#comment30330115_20306721). 
It deals with the field "system_indicator" in the manifest both for app and extension (dev branch only).
Tanks !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306548/how-to-use-system-indicator-in-the-manisfet-of-a-chrome-packaged-app#comment30330115_20306721), there is a solution (chrome dev-channel only for now).

It works for both apps and extensions.

See the Chrome bug here : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142450
And two example here : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/test/data/extensions/api_test/system_indicator/

Thanks [@Sergey Shevchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2145606/sergey-shevchenko) for his help.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the experimental API support for `system_indicator` has been dropped (look for the recent comments in [issue 142450](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142450). In other words, as for now, there is no API for a system tray icon.