# How to show google chrome apps icon in system tray

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

How to show google chrome apps icon  in system tray and also hide the icon from task bar when minimise the window using javascript,jquery,google chrome extension

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757348/system-tray-icon-for-chrome-extension

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Solution https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lightning-reopen/ahphokgmcecbjeipkfkamcdmemghkaph

it is exactly what you're looking for I'm  Currently using it and its sole purpose is to put Google Chrome in the system tray and let it run in the background, That's it.

Here is a direct quote from the developers page describing this Google Chrome extension

> Keep Chrome open in the background for faster re-opening
>   Do you have a million extensions installed that take absolutely ages to load when you open a new Chrome window, causing freezes and stuttering? Do you want to get notifications from your browser extensions without having to keep a Chrome window open and cluttering your taskbar? Do you have more RAM than you know what to do with?
>
> If you answered yes to at least one of the questions above then this extension is for you! After installing, Chrome will sit in your notification area and remain open in the background, which means that when you open a new Chrome window all your extensions will not need to re-initialize themselves resulting in a lot faster startup and next to no lag.
>
> For the longest time I've been just installing Dropbox for Gmail on all my machines to get this effect, but taking a look at what permissions it has made me realize that maybe I should not be doing that. I decided to make my own background extension with no permissions, no cryptominers and no API calls "phoning home".
>
> That's right, this extension literally has no way to access any of your personal data anywhere while you're browsing, its only purpose is to let you keep Chrome in the background. Even if at any point the extension were to be compromised you would be prompted for any extra permissions, which you should never agree to. You have my word that this extension will never be sold to any shady extension marketing company looking to inject ads and/or trackers into every page you visit.

This extension is open source, you can find the source code here: https://github.com/SeinopSys/LightningReopen

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That's not a thing that Chrome extensions can do.

[There was, at one point, some work towards an API](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142450) to allow Chrome extensions to display "system indicators" (i.e, system tray icons, menu bar icons, etc). However, this work was abandoned; there is no support for this feature in any current version of Chrome, nor is there likely to ever be.

If you want a system tray icon, you will need to write a native application.

Comment: the "google hangouts extension" (v 2017.420.419.1) for google chrome adds an icon in my system tray (ubuntu)  shown at all times (next to volume and the clock). a new API?

Comment: ugh. Apparently hangouts is whitelisted in the source code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614493/how-does-the-google-hangouts-extension-create-the-panel-window/11614605#11614605